# Jasmine Testing: how to access an element that is part of an ng-template?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have a test that is trying to grab an element, click it, and confirm that a method is executed.

Example template:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="testTemplate"> </ng-container>

<ng-template #testTemplate>
  <button id="testButton" (click)="testMethod()"></button>
<ng-template>
```

In spec file:

```
const testButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#testButton')); // returns null
```

If I move the button outside of the ng-template in the HTML, it is able to find the button just fine. What are ways around this?

Comment: Could you add what your test does before querying the testButton? I.e. what is done in the beforeEach, what happens in the test before the line you quoted.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?